# magento 2 remove leading zeros from order number everywhere

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, custom, sales

In magento 2 i want to remove leading zeros from the order numbers.

Order Number looks like:  0000012351

i want order number to look like 12351 without any leading zero.

How can i modify it?

Comment: Are you apply it for new order or existing order?

Comment: i want to apply for new order and existing orders as well.

Comment: @SHPatel   if i want to change in order confirmation email only then?

Comment: You can check these plugins: https://github.com/aligent/Magento_SetStartOrderNumber and https://amasty.com/custom-order-number.html

Comment: @SejalShah If i want to do it programmatically then?  i can not afford to buy extension.  Do you have any idea how can i do that?